# How to checkout only a particular subdirectory given parent directory is not checkedout

Tags: svn, version-control, svn-checkout, svn-update

Say, I have checkout a empty branch

```
foo/
```

and, I want to simply checkout only a particular subdirectory somewhat deep inside, say

```
foo/1/2/3/4
```

I am only interested in checkout the full subdirectory `4`, nothing else.

I tried

```
svn up foo/1/2/3/4
```

but it didn't work, gives error

**Can't create directory 'foo/1/2/3/4': No such file or directory**

How do I make it work if the subdirectory `1` is locally non-existent to begin with? Do we have to do separate `svn up` for each subdirectory one by one?

Note that:

```
svn up foo/1
```

works!

Comment: The `foo` branch is empty or not? If empty how can checkout/update the `foo/1/2/...`?

Comment: Yes it is empty to begin with as I mentioned in ques "the subdirectory `1` is locally non-existent"

Answer (score 0):

My solution for the case when the parent directories (in above case `1`, `2`, `3`) are non-existent.

Actually `svn up` works only upto one level. That's if `foo` is existing (and is empty), then we can do update only upto `svn up foo\1`, and no svn URL is required.

That would mean checking out all sub-directories and files under `foo\1`, which we don't really want, as it may be huge in size.

Instead the simple solution is to do

```
svn co svn-url-to-subdirectory path-to-subdirectory
```